# find and get particular word using regular expression

Tags: regex, node.js, shell

Am trying to find and get particular word from a data returnd

While i executing a partiular command `console.log(stdout)` prints below data

```
commit e6c4236951634c67218172d742
Author:ttpn <testuser@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Jun 9 10:18:04 2014 -0700

    Fix it dersk reset

..........
...........
```

my code

```
var getemail = function (callback) {
  var command = "git show ec6c4236951634c67218172d742";
  exec(command, function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    if (error !== null) {
      console.log(error)
      callback(error, null);
    } else {
console.log(stdout) // prints the above data

    }
  })
```

;
}

from this how can i get `email id`  `testuser@gmail.com`
using regular expression is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex will capture the data you want to Groups 1 and 2 (on the [demo](http://regex101.com/r/eT5sX2), look at the capture Groups in the right pane):

```
commit (\S+)[\r\n]*Author:[^<]*<([^>]*)>
```

Here is how to use this in JS:

```
var regex = /commit (\S+)[\r\n]*Author:[^<]*<([^>]*)>/;
var match = regex.exec(string);
if (match != null) {
    theid = match[1];
    theemail = match[2];
}
```

**Explaining the Regex**

```
commit                   # 'commit '
(                        # group and capture to \1:
  \S+                    #   non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f,
                         #   and " ") (1 or more times (matching the
                         #   most amount possible))
)                        # end of \1
[\r\n]*                  # any character of: '\r' (carriage return),
                         # '\n' (newline) (0 or more times (matching
                         # the most amount possible))
Author:                  # 'Author:'
[^<]*                    # any character except: '<' (0 or more times
                         # (matching the most amount possible))
<                        # '<'
(                        # group and capture to \2:
  [^>]*                  #   any character except: '>' (0 or more
                         #   times (matching the most amount
                         #   possible))
)                        # end of \2
>                        # '>'
```